# Custom rule for SUTime is not working

Tags: stanford-nlp, sutime

I'm trying to annotate things like `in 10 minutes`, but for some reason I can't get it work.

I'm using a custom model file for my rules which is loaded after *defs.sutime.txt*, *english.sutime.txt* and *english.holidays.sutime.txt*.

My current rule is this:

```
{ 
    ( /in/ (?$a [ { temporal::IS_TIMEX_DURATION } ] ) )
    =>
    RelativeTime( $a[0].temporal.value )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ENV.defaults["ruleType"] = "composite"

{
    ( /in/ (?$a [ { temporal::IS_TIMEX_DURATION } ] ) )
    =>
    TemporalCompose( OFFSET, TIME_REF, $a[0].temporal )
}
```